# recompile existing objective c library to support arm8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

One of the project we are currently working on uses a static objective-c library created by an ex employee.

The problem we have is that the library was built for arm7 which has 32 bit architecture. Is there a way to recompile for new architecture. It seems like a long shot though.

___**Edited** I don't have the source code.

Comment: a) what does the age of the employee have to do with anything? b) yes, there is a way to recompile -- just use a modern version of Xcode and, if necessary, change the build settings of your target to the correct architectures. b-prime) I assume you mean you have the source code to this library and are not asking about "recompiling" the binary.

Comment: I think the OP meant "ex employee" rather than an employee who was advanced in years. :)

Comment: we don't have the source code. The employee created the library but didn't leave the source anywhere in source control. That is the issue we have

Comment: "arm8" seems to be the family name to which the architecture armv4 belongs. I'm sure you meant armv8 (64 bit). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures

Comment: Ouch. If an employee writes code as part of his job then that source belongs to the employer. You should try contacting the ex and ask where the source is. It's a small world, and if he cares about his reputation, he'll help track it down.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the source code and Xcode project? If so, the answer is yes. As mah says, you may have to refactor the project for the latest IDE.

If you don't have the source code then the answer is a resounding "NO!" Compiling means converting source code into machine code. No source code = nothing to compile. You might be able to analyze the machine code and reverse-engineer it, but that's a horrific amount of work.

Comment: Thanks. I figured. Just wanted to be sure.